# Regex to validate 150 character text in HTML format

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want a regex which will limit the character count to 150 and at the same time allow HTML.
So far I have reached this much `^.{0,150}$` but this won't allow html tags. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You mean that stuff within HTML tags is excluded from the 150 character count?

Comment: Also, you might want to ditch the `$` in the pattern. Otherwise it will match everything until the string passes 150 characters, then it will match nothing. (Well, 75 characters, as the pattern stands currently.)

Comment: @Abion47 Yes, I want 150 characters. And I don't mind what ever html tag they add in between them. Can you put the correct regex as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use a Regex like this:

```
^(?><(.+?)>.+?<\/\1>|.){0,150}
```

It's not perfect, as instead of ignoring HTML tags entirely it will instead treat the whole string between the opening and closing tag like a single character. It's a start, though.